# Redirect URI is changed from HTTP to HTTPS

Tags: redirect, google-drive-api

What may cause the issue that the Redirect URI are changed and are not the same as added in Google API Console ?

The redirect URI is added like this, have worked for at least 1 year now.
http://www.company.com/OAuth2Callback

But today instead of using that URI, we have seen that the underlying callback logic from Google is going to a HTTPS page: **https**://www.company.com/OAuth2Callback

Our webserver uses the OAuth2.0 to also login customers.
All our customers then instead comes to a page 'this page has no valid certificate..', instead of being logged in.

And since the server does not respond with this, and do not have a correct certificate this give an error on the web-server, customers are trying to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the hoster is changing it? Because at my hoster you can ask to automatically change the url from HTTP to HTTPS.

Comment: Looks like you where right. The network guys had updated the firmware on the routers and that had changed the URI.